# Casper test in coffee wont' compile with javascript syntax in evaluate()

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

I've been writing my casperJS tests in coffeescript and I execute alot of code in the client environment using casper.evaluate(). However it seems like when I use a javascript specific syntax like function(){}, the casper test won't compile and trying to run it just shoots out an error.

Does anyone else have this problem and know a fix?

Comment: Can you post an example with the error you receive? The CS notation for `function(){}` is simply `->`.

Comment: It's just a caspererror can't find module (file) since it doesn't compile. I know the coffee notation but using coffeescript within the casper.evaluate() won't work since the codes are executed in the browser context which can't interpret coffeescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now just writing the entire code in coffee, compiling it into javascript and then running the test.

EDIT: Don't know how i just realized this but coffeescript code in evaluate works fine...